# How can I set the billing and shipping addresses on an order that I am creating programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, programmatically, edit-order

I am creating a duplicate order that has been previously placed by a specific customer. How can I set the same billing and shipping address on the new order that I am creating programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load any data from the existing order object.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oldOrderId);
$order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
```

Another way would be to use the old orders quote

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oldOrderId);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId();

$quote->collectTotals();

$converter = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');
$order = $convert->toOrder($quote)
    ->setPayment($converter->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment()))
    ->setShippingAddress($converter->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress()))
    ->setBillingAddress($converter->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()));

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem);
    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
        $orderItem->setParentItem($order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getParentItem()->getId()));
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->save();
```

*disclaimer:*

*1. got the code from an old script, didn't test it and might need some debuggen here and there*

*2. if you have the quote cleanup cron working quotes will be thrown away after 30 days so can't be loaded*